# Swift ranking dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swift5

I'm able to ranking a dictionary of string and int.
But my solution look like no smart and "swifty"

**The problem is when more teams have same points and same rank as "team 2" and "team 4"**

**ex dic input**

```
var dict:[String:Int] = ["team1":79,"team2":5, "team3":18, "team4":5, "team5": 82, "team6":1]
```

**output**

> [(team: "team5", rank: 1), (team: "team1", rank: 2), (team: "team3",
>   rank: 3), (team: "team2", rank: 4), (team: "team4", rank: 4), (team: "team6", rank: 5)]

the code:

```
var ris = [(team:String,rank:Int)]()
var pos = 1

let sorted = dict.sorted(by:{$0.value > $1.value})
print(sorted)
for (i, element) in sorted.enumerated() {

    if i == 0 ||  element.value == sorted[i-1].value {

    }
    else {
        pos += 1
    }
    ris.append((team:element.key,rank:pos))
}
let ranking = ris.sorted(by:{$0.rank < $1.rank})
print(ranking)
```

prints:

> [(team: "team5", rank: 1), (team: "team1", rank: 2), (team: "team3",
>   rank: 3), (team: "team2", rank: 4), (team: "team4", rank: 4), (team: "team6", rank: 5)]

ok it's works, but I'm sure I'm missing something better using some closure of sorted, maps flapmaps etc

anyone?

Comment: The `i > sorted.count` case doesn't do anything; it will never be hit.

Comment: sure, was a refuse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simplify it a bit by grouping teams with identical scores in a dictionary first. Then sort the dictionary (according to decreasing score), enumerate it (to get the offsets) and build the ranking list:

```
let dict:[String:Int] = ["team1":79, "team2":5, "team3":18, "team4":5, "team5": 82, "team6": 1]

let ranking = Dictionary(grouping: dict, by: { $0.value })
    .sorted(by: { $0.key > $1.key })
    .enumerated()
    .flatMap { (offset, elem) in
        elem.value.map { (team: $0.key, rank: offset + 1 )}
    }

print(ranking)
// [(team: "team5", rank: 1), (team: "team1", rank: 2),
//  (team: "team3", rank: 3), (team: "team2", rank: 4),
//  (team: "team4", rank: 4), (team: "team6", rank: 5)]]
```

---

A detailed explanation:

```
Dictionary(grouping: dict, by: { $0.value })
```

creates a dictionary whose keys are the team scores, and whose values are arrays of the teams with that score.

```
.sorted(by: { $0.key > $1.key })
```

sorts the dictionary by decreasing keys, the result is an array of tuples:

```
 [(key: 82, value: [(key: "team5", value: 82)]),
  (key: 79, value: [(key: "team1", value: 79)]),
  (key: 18, value: [(key: "team3", value: 18)]),
  (key: 5, value: [(key: "team2", value: 5), (key: "team4", value: 5)]),
  (key: 1, value: [(key: "team6", value: 1)])]
```

Then

```
.enumerated()
```

creates a lazy sequence of (offset, element) pairs from this array:

```
  (offset: 0, element: (key: 82, value: [(key: "team5", value: 82)])),
  (offset: 1, element: (key: 79, value: [(key: "team1", value: 79)])),
  (offset: 2, element: (key: 18, value: [(key: "team3", value: 18)])),
  (offset: 3, element: (key: 5, value: [(key: "team2", value: 5), (key: "team4", value: 5)])),
  (offset: 4, element: (key: 1, value: [(key: "team6", value: 1)]))
```

Finally `flatMap` calls the closure on each (offset, element) pair and concatenates the result. Inside the closure,

```
 elem.value.map { (team: $0.key, rank: offset + 1 )}
```

maps an (offset, element) pair and to an array of (team, rank) tuples. For example,

```
  (offset: 3, element: (key: 5, value: [(key: "team2", value: 5), (key: "team4", value: 5)]))
```

is mapped to

```
 [(team: "team2", rank: 4), (team: "team4", rank: 4)]
```

`flatMap()` concatenates these arrays, giving the final `ranking` array.

---

This is the originally posted solution, which produces the ranks 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 6 for the sample data (instead of 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5):

```
let dict:[String:Int] = ["team1":79, "team2":5, "team3":18, "team4":5, "team5": 82, "team6": 1]

var ranking = [(team:String,rank:Int)]()
for (_, list) in Dictionary(grouping: dict, by: { $0.value })
    .sorted(by: { $0.key > $1.key }) {
        let pos = ranking.count + 1
        ranking.append(contentsOf: list.map { ($0.key, pos )})
}

print(ranking)
// [(team: "team5", rank: 1), (team: "team1", rank: 2),
//  (team: "team3", rank: 3), (team: "team4", rank: 4),
//  (team: "team2", rank: 4), (team: "team6", rank: 6)]
```

Comment: your solution looking good, but there is a problem if there is a "team6":1 --> prints rank 6 instead 5

Comment: @SimonePistecchia: I thought that is what you want. – But actually that makes it simpler, see update.

Comment: @SimonePistecchia So if there's a tie, the score should be something like `[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 6]` ?

Comment: it should be [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5]

Comment: Very good solution, thanks. It will be useful if you put also the previous solution [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 6]

Comment: @SimonePistecchia: I have added it again.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a much simpler solution :)

```
let teamScores = [
    "team1":79,
    "team2":5,
    "team3":18,
    "team4":5,
    "team5": 82
]

let teamRanks = teamScores
    .sorted(by: { $0.value > $1.value})
    .enumerated()
    .map { (offset: Int, pair: (team: String, score: Int)) -> (team: String, rank: Int) in
        let rank = offset + 1
        return (team: pair.team, rank: rank)
    }

print(teamRanks)
```

- You sort the team scores so that the highest scores come first
- Enumerate the sequence so you have access to the indices (where 0 is the best team, 1 is the second best team, ...)
- Map over the elements rename the tuple members, and to add one to all of the offsets (which form the 1 based indices)

If you want tied scores to be given the same rank, then the type signatures get a bit more hairy, but the idea is similar:

```
let teamScores = [
    "team1":79,
    "team2":5,
    "team3":18,
    "team4":5,
    "team5": 82
]

let teamRanks = Dictionary(grouping: teamScores, by: { $0.value })
    .sorted(by: { $0.key > $1.key })
    .enumerated()
    .flatMap { (
        offset: Int,
        ranks: (
            commonScore: Int,
            teamScores: [(key: String, value: Int)]
        )
    ) -> [(team: String, rank: Int)] in
        let rank = offset + 1
        return ranks.teamScores.map { (team: $0.key, rank: rank) }
    }

print(teamRanks)
```

Comment: Note that "team2" and "team4" have the same score (5) and – as I understand it from the sample output –  should have the same rank (4).

Comment: Right, "team2" and "team4" should have the same rank (4)

Answer (score 1):

I think `.sorted(by:)` is enough for this question, here is my solution:

```
// name and score
let dict = [ 
    "Sam": 79, "Joe": 5, "Mary": 79,
    "Tom": 5, "Alex": 82, "Nancy": 1 
] 

// ⭐️ 1. sort it by value first
let sorted = dict.sorted { $0.value > $1.value }

var index = 0
var prev: Int?              // previous score
var currentRank = 0
var rankingList = [(name: String, score: Int, rank: Int)]()

// 2. give every element a rank
for elem in sorted {
    
    // increase index
    index += 1
    
    // if elem.value is not the same as previous score,
    // update previous score and current rank
    if prev == nil || elem.value != prev! {
        prev = elem.value
        currentRank = index
    }
    
    rankingList.append((elem.key, elem.value, currentRank))
}

print(rankingList)
/*
[
    (name: "Alex" , score: 82, rank: 1), 
    (name: "Sam"  , score: 79, rank: 2), 
    (name: "Mary" , score: 79, rank: 2),    // no 3rd place
    (name: "Joe"  , score:  5, rank: 4), 
    (name: "Tom"  , score:  5, rank: 4),    // no 5th place
    (name: "Nancy", score:  1, rank: 6)
]
*/
```

You could write a dedicated extension for this situation if you wanted to:

```
extension Sequence {
    // sequence.statefulMap(_:result:)
    func statefulMap<State, Result>(
        // intial local state
        _ initialState: State, 
        // calculate the result from current element & state,
        // current state may be updated upon each call.
        result: (Element, inout State) -> Result
    ) -> [Result] { 
        var state = initialState
        return map { elem in 
            return result(elem, &state)
        } 
    }
}

// example dictionary
let dict = [
    "Sam": 79, "Joe": 5, "Mary": 79,
    "Tom": 5, "Alex": 82, "Nancy": 1
]

// local state for .statefulMap()
typealias State = (prev: Int?, currentRank: Int, index: Int)
// result type for .statefulMap()
typealias Result = (name: String, score: Int, rank: Int)

let intialState: State = (prev: nil, currentRank: 0, index: 0)

let list = dict
    .sorted { $0.value > $1.value }
    .statefulMap(intialState) { (elem, state: inout State) -> Result in
        // increase index
        state.index += 1
        // if elem.value is not the same as previous score,
        // update previous score and current rank
        if state.prev == nil || elem.value != state.prev! {
            state.prev = elem.value
            state.currentRank = state.index
        }
        return (elem.key, elem.value, state.currentRank)
    }

print(list)
```

And the result is the same.